# How to sum value in a specific object?

Tags: java, oop

I have this code where you would search for the patient ID and when found a sub menu will show, the user would then be prompted to choose. If the user chooses bill the would then be asked to enter a transaction and it would be summed to the balance in the same object as the ID that was searched. However when the user inputs a value it always sums the value to the balance(450) in the object.

How can I fix this?

NB: it's in an array

output: adds the input to the first object only.

````
patient pAccount[] = new patient [10];

    patient p1 = new patient("Jabari","luck",d1 ,"234-4343", "p01" ,450);
        
        patient p2 = new patient("Lisa", "nun", d2,"311-5634" , "p02",300);
        
        patient p3 = new patient("Kyle", "Hep",d3  ,"555-5555" , "p03",2000 );

//search array for patient ID
public static void ID(person [] pAccount) {
        
                Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
                
                String num = scan.next();
                for(int i=0; i< pAccount.length; i++) {
                    
                    
                        if (pAccount[i].getpatID().equals(num)) {
                            System.out.println("found");
                            break;
                            }   
                    
                            
                        
                    }
                    }       

//sum user input to balance
public static void bill(person[] pAccount) {
        
         Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
         double sum;
         
          double num= in.nextDouble();
          for(int i=0; i <= pAccount.length; i++) {
              person ad= pAccount[i];
            
                sum = ((patient) ad).getbalance()+ num;
             
                  System.out.println("Balance: " +sum);
                  break;
              
          }  
             
    }```
````

Comment: What exactly is the bug in the code? What is broken?

Comment: @nicomp it sums the user input to the wrong object. It suppose to sum the input to the balance in the same object as the ID that was search.

Comment: You should edit your question and clearly explain that.

Comment: May be you should try removing break statement in the for loop, that might be causing the issue. Because when i=0, your summing into pAccount[0] and breaking out of the loop. So, it is always adding it to first object, that is amount with 450

Comment: @BSangappa I tried that but I kept getting  a null pointer exception and I don't know much about exceptions

Answer (score 0):

what I understood from your question is, you need to add sum to the balance of a specific object in Patient Object array. Below is the way to do,

**(I excluded few member variables which I didn't get just by looking at Object creation in your question and kept only *name, patId and balance*  in Patient Class. Also I assumed you've Constructor with all the fields)**

I took your code and modified a little for you requirement. You can refer comments I added in the code snippets.

PatientMainClass.class

```
public class PatientMainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Patient pAccount[] = new Patient[3];

    Patient p1 = new Patient("Jabari", "p01", 450);
    pAccount[0] = p1;
    Patient p2 = new Patient("Lisa", "p02", 300);
    pAccount[1] = p2;
    Patient p3 = new Patient("Kyle", "p03", 2000);
    pAccount[2] = p3;
    
    //Use bill method to add Amount to existing balance of all the Patient Objects
    Patient.bill(pAccount);
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < pAccount.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("After adding amount to the Balance of pAccount[" + i + "] is : " + pAccount[i].getBalance());
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    //Use billToSpecific method to add Amount to specific Patient Object
    //to billToSpecific method, pass both Patient Array and Patient ID to which you want to add Amount
    Patient.billToSpecificPatient(pAccount, "p02");
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < pAccount.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("After adding amount to p02, Balance of pAccount[" + i + "] is : " + pAccount[i].getBalance());
    }
            

} }
```

Patient.class

```
public class Patient {

private String name;
private String patId;
private double balance;

public Patient(String name, String patId, double balance) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.patId = patId;
    this.balance = balance;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPatId() {
    return patId;
}

public void setPatId(String patId) {
    this.patId = patId;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

// This method will Add entered value i.e.. "num" to the Balance of all the Patient Objects
public static void bill(Patient[] pAccount) {
    System.out.println("In bill method");           // Always try using System.out.println for Debugging
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double sum;

    double num = in.nextDouble();
    for (int i = 0; i < pAccount.length; i++) {
        Patient ad = pAccount[i];

        sum = ((Patient) ad).getBalance() + num;
        ad.setBalance(sum);
        System.out.println("Balance: " + sum);
        // break;                                   // Commenting break statement to add balance to all the Objects

    }

}

// This method will Add entered value i.e.. "num" to the Balance of the Specific Patient Object
public static void billToSpecificPatient(Patient[] pAccount, String patId) {
    System.out.println("In billToSpecific method"); // Always try using System.out.println for Debugging
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double sum;

    double num = in.nextDouble();
    for (int i = 0; i < pAccount.length; i++) {
        if (pAccount[i].getPatId().equals(patId)) {
            Patient ad = pAccount[i];
            sum = ((Patient) ad).getBalance() + num;
            ad.setBalance(sum);
            System.out.println("Balance: " + sum);
            break;                                  // Using break statement to exit the loop once we add amount to specific Patient Object
        }

    }

} }
```

I guess, you can now resolve your issue with the help of these code snippets. Hope it is helpful.